# Relationship between $H^1(M)$ of 3-manifolds and maps $M \to S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

Let $M$ be a closed, connected, orientable 3-manifold. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336780/representation-of-cohomology-classes-of-3-manifolds-by-embedded-surfaces), it is stated that (integer coefficients)

$$H_2(M) \cong H^1(M) \cong \langle M,S^1\rangle.$$

$\langle M,S^1\rangle$ is the group of homotopy classes of maps $M \to S^1$. The first $\cong$ is Poincare duality. **What is the second isomorphism?** I've not seen it before. Is it discussed in, say, Hatcher, or other standard reference? Can it be visualized? (The linked answer is concerned with embedded, orientable surfaces, which I believe are the means of visualization.)

Comment: It's (a special case of) Theorem 4.57 in Hatcher.

Comment: $H_1(M)$ in the title?

Comment: @PaulFrost corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Letting $\gamma \in H^1(S^1) \approx \mathbb Z$ be a generator, there is a function $\phi : \langle M, S^1 \rangle \to H^1(M)$ defined by
$$\phi[f] = f^*(\gamma)
$$
for each continuous $f : M \to S^1$, where $[f] \in \langle M,S^1 \rangle$ denotes the homotopy class of $f$, and $f^* : H^1(S^1) \to H^1(M)$ denotes the homomorphism induced by $f$ with respect to the contravariant functor $H^1(\cdot)$.

The theorem you need is that this function $\phi$ is a bijection. As said in the comments, this theorem can be found in Hatcher's book, and also in many other algebraic topology books; I first learned it in Spanier's book.

In the special case that $M$ is an oriented manifold, you can evaluate $\phi[f]$ by first homotoping $f$ to be transverse to a point $p \in S^1$, in which case $f^{-1}(p)$ is a codimension 1 transversely oriented submanifold of $M$. By pairing that transverse orientation with the orientation of $M$ one obtains an orientation of $f^{-1}(p)$, which therefore represents an element of $H_{n-1}(M)$ where $n$ is the dimension of $M$. In this situation $\phi[f]$ is the Poincaré dual of the homology class of $f^{-1}(p)$. To put it another way, $\phi[f] \in H^1(M)$ is evaluated on each 1-dimensional homology class in $M$ by taking the intersection number of that class (i.e. the algebraic intersection number of any 1-cycle in that class) with $f^{-1}(p)$.

A similar construction of $\phi[f]$ also works for the case that $M$ is a simplicial complex: choose $f$ to be in general position with respect to $p$, in which case $f^{-1}(p)$ is a transversely oriented subcomplex with a product neighborhood. In this case $\phi[f] \in H^1(M)$ is defined by evaluating it on an arbitrary cycle in $M$ to be the algebraic intersection number of that cycle with $f^{-1}(p)$.

Comment: In either the manifold or simplicial case, when calculating the algebraic intersection number, how do we account for cycles that intersect $f^{-1}(p)$ tangentially? In the simplicial case, can't $f^{-1}(p)$ itself touch a 1-cell tangentially?

Comment: This is done using general position methods. First prove that every $1$-cycle is homologous to one that intersects $f^{-1}(p)$ transversely. Then prove that for any homologous pair of $1$-cycles each of which intersects $f^{-1}(p)$ transversely, there exists a homology between then (i.e. an appropriate 2-chain) that intersects $f^{-1}(p)$ transversely.

Comment: One more question. I am comfortable with the fact that smooth maps of manifolds have preimage (at regular values) a manifold. In the manifold case: are we supposing $f$ is smooth, not just continuous? In the simplicial case: I'm assuming $f$ is just continuous, but how do we know $f^{-1}(p)$ has that structure you describe? Is there any book I can look for this in?

Comment: In the simplicial case, is there simple reason to at least believe that the preimage of the general point is some topologically embedded codim=1 subspace?

Comment: It sounds like for the simplicial case you might like to learn some PL topology. It's not a fashionable subject, but there is a good old textbook by Roarke and Sanderson. General position arguments in the smooth case can be generalized to the simplicial case.

Comment: For the case that $M$ is a smooth manifold, these are standard arguments in transversality theory: every continuous map $M \mapsto S^1$ is homotopic to a smooth map that is transverse to the point $p$; and for any two smooth maps transverse to the point $p$ that are homotopic to each other, there exists a smooth homotopy that is transverse to the point $p$. These concepts are all covered in a differential topology course, such as the book by Guillleman and Pollack.